# How to use Laravel whereYear in varchar column?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I want to filter the year in my varchar column named `schedule` using laravel `whereYear()`. However it returns an error shown in the image below. One more thing is that, I am not pointing the `whereYear` to `created_at` date column in the database that everyone is using. Below is my code. Please help. Thanks.

**Controller:**

```
$year = $request['bill_year'];
$month = $request['bill_month'];
$period = $request['bill_period'];

if( is_numeric($year) ){

      $amortizations = Amortization::whereYear('schedule', $year)->where('bill_status',0)->get();

      if($amortizations){
         $notification = "Success";
       } else{
         $notification = "Failed";
       }

       return json_encode(array('notify'=>$notification, 'amortizations' => $amortizations, 'year' => $year, 'month' => $month, 'period' => $period));                                           
}
```

**Column `'schedule'` in the database**

[image]

**error:**

[image]

**error using answer by Akash Kumar Verma**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

WhereYear working with Y-m-d H:i:s  timestamp format

```php
use DB;
```

```php
$amortizations = Amortization::where( DB::raw('YEAR(schedule)'), $year )->where('bill_status',0)->get();
```

or

```php
$amortizations = Amortization::whereRaw('YEAR(schedule) = '.$year)->where('bill_status',0)->get();
```

Comment: it says DB not found anyway :(

Comment: use DB; at top.

Comment: I posted the error message using your answer. Please take a look at the error image above. Thank you.

Comment: what is the datatype of schedule

Comment: I still get the same error using the other line of code